# Single Item selection based on multiple filters

Tags: selection, multi-selection

Below is a set of filters that effect what `Items` are displayed in a list. Changes to the filters update the filter the list of `items` in an `OR`ed fashion. The user may select from the `Items` displayed in the list, as either single selection, contiguous multi-selection (via `[shift]`), or dis-contiguous mutli-selection (via `[ctrl]` or checkboxes).

This pattern seems good to me for instances of user selection

where

- Users need multi-selection
- Users need multiple layers of filtration of find Items

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f80TJK.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

---

Below is an expandable 'type ahead', where there is a single filter that filters a list if `Items`. The User may select a single `Item` from the list of `Items` by clicking on it, or pressing `[Enter]` while that `Item` is in :focus.

This pattern seems good to me for instances of user selection

where

- Users need single selection
- Users need a single layer of filtration to find Items

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJvUjR.png)</sup>

---

So, here's the question. Is there a good middle ground pattern? One best suited for instances

where

- Users need single selection
- Users need multiple layers of filtration to find Items

?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to specify which criteria you will use to define "good".

Here is a pattern used by [Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira), that is suited for multiple filters and single selection:

https://youtu.be/xrCJv0fTyR8?t=1m17s

In case the video gets deleted in the future, here are some screenshots. Jira has 2 modes for filtering. The **Advanced** mode is for typing. It has a textarea:

[image]

The user can type in and the auto-completion will provide options:
[image]

The filters can be combined:
[image]

The results are shown below the filter bar, as a list of clickable items:
[image]

The other mode is the **Basic**, with the list of types of filters already presented ins a row:
[image]

Choosing one filter type opens a box with advanced controls:
[image]

Comment: This is ultimately the same as the pattern I showed for multi-filter multi-selection, but with a custom query language. Its certainly not the light-weight solution I was hoping for.